# How to correctly skip tests based on the test params?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a small test that uses `@pytest.parametrize`

```
import pytest

class TestBla:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('arg', (True, False))
    def test(self, arg):
        assert arg
```

I want to skip the `False` case instead of running and failing it, so I added the following fixture to the test:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def skipper(self, request):
    if request.getfixturevalue('arg') is False:
        pytest.skip()
```

and it works great: `pytest -s test_skips.py` is skipping the `False` and passing the `True`.

- My problem is this: This fixture depends on the function having an `'arg'` param. **What if someone changes its name?** Can I make this more robust?
- The reason this skip is done in a fixture and not in the test itself is to make the test short as possible and move all other logic outside. **Is this a bad idea?**

BTW, I learned today that [skipper is from Dutch](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/skipper).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do to make things cleaner is to use a specific mark for your decisions and then querying the marks from the pytest_runtest_setup hook method in conftest.py:

```
@pytest.mark.supported_browsers('chrome', 'firefox')
def test_try(self):
    # test logic
```

and then in conftest.py:

```
def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    current_browser = Environment.get().current_browser
    if _has_marker(item=item, marker_name='supported_browsers'):
        supported_browsers_marker_list = _get_marker(item, marker_name='supported_browsers')
        supported_browsers = supported_browsers_marker_list[0].args
        if current_browser not in supported_browsers:
            pytest.skip(f'This test does not support this type browser.')
            return


def _has_marker(item, marker_name: str) -> bool:
    return len(list(item.iter_markers(name=marker_name))) > 0


def _get_marker(item, marker_name) -> typing.Optional[typing.List]:
    if _has_marker(item=item, marker_name=marker_name):
        return list(item.iter_markers(name=marker_name))
    else:
        return None
```

more information can be found here:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html